# ¿ Como se crea un botón que despliegue mas botones?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, botón

Tengo una serie de botones de redes sociales, encontrado en la comunidad, y en uno de ellos quería poner uno que al pasar por encima el ratón me 
desplegara automáticamente mas botones de redes sociales.
No lo consigo, y por mas que busque solo vi en el [ejemplo de CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzRZpr)
Pero no esta el código, por lo que no se como hacerlo.
Espero haberme explicado para con lo que les muestro puedan ayudarme, o decirme donde buscar.
Gracias.

```js
$(function() {
 
 const ARTICLE_TITLE =  document.title;
 const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
 const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

 $('.share-fb').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
 });

 $('.share-twitter').click(function(){
  open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
 });

 $('.share-google-plus').click(function(){
  open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
 });

 $('.share-linkedin').click(function(){
  open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&title='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
 });

 $('.share-pinterest').click(function(){
  open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&media='+MAIN_IMAGE_URL+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
 });
 
 $('.share-tumblr').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&name='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
 });

 function open_window(url, name){
  window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
 }
});
```

```css
.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; 
    -webkit-align-items: center; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}


.share-fb{
    background-color: #2d609b;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter{
    background-color: #00c3f3;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48IURPQ1RZUEUgc3ZnIFBVQkxJQyAiLS8vVzNDLy9EVEQgU1ZHIDEuMS8vRU4iICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9HcmFwaGljcy9TVkcvMS4xL0RURC9zdmcxMS5kdGQiPjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTMyIDYuMDc2Yy0xLjE3NyAwLjUyMi0yLjQ0MyAwLjg3NS0zLjc3MSAxLjAzNCAxLjM1NS0wLjgxMyAyLjM5Ni0yLjA5OSAyLjg4Ny0zLjYzMi0xLjI2OSAwLjc1Mi0yLjY3NCAxLjI5OS00LjE2OSAxLjU5My0xLjE5OC0xLjI3Ni0yLjkwNC0yLjA3My00Ljc5Mi0yLjA3My0zLjYyNiAwLTYuNTY1IDIuOTM5LTYuNTY1IDYuNTY1IDAgMC41MTUgMC4wNTggMS4wMTYgMC4xNyAxLjQ5Ni01LjQ1Ni0wLjI3NC0xMC4yOTQtMi44ODgtMTMuNTMyLTYuODYtMC41NjUgMC45Ny0wLjg4OSAyLjA5Ny0wLjg4OSAzLjMwMSAwIDIuMjc4IDEuMTU5IDQuMjg3IDIuOTIxIDUuNDY1LTEuMDc2LTAuMDM0LTIuMDg4LTAuMzI5LTIuOTc0LTAuODIxLTAuMDAxIDAuMDI3LTAuMDAxIDAuMDU1LTAuMDAxIDAuMDgzIDAgMy4xODEgMi4yNjMgNS44MzQgNS4yNjYgNi40MzctMC41NTEgMC4xNS0xLjEzMSAwLjIzLTEuNzMgMC4yMy0wLjQyMyAwLTAuODM0LTAuMDQxLTEuMjM1LTAuMTE4IDAuODM1IDIuNjA4IDMuMjYgNC41MDYgNi4xMzMgNC41NTktMi4yNDcgMS43NjEtNS4wNzggMi44MS04LjE1NCAyLjgxLTAuNTMgMC0xLjA1Mi0wLjAzMS0xLjU2Ni0wLjA5MiAyLjkwNSAxLjg2MyA2LjM1NiAyLjk1IDEwLjA2NCAyLjk1IDEyLjA3NiAwIDE4LjY3OS0xMC4wMDQgMTguNjc5LTE4LjY4IDAtMC4yODUtMC4wMDYtMC41NjgtMC4wMTktMC44NDkgMS4yODMtMC45MjYgMi4zOTYtMi4wODIgMy4yNzYtMy4zOTh6Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+);
}

.share-google-plus{
    background-color: #eb4026;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin{
    background-color: #0074a1;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48IURPQ1RZUEUgc3ZnIFBVQkxJQyAiLS8vVzNDLy9EVEQgU1ZHIDEuMS8vRU4iICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9HcmFwaGljcy9TVkcvMS4xL0RURC9zdmcxMS5kdGQiPjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTI2LjYyNSAwaC0yMS4yNWMtMi45NTYgMC01LjM3NSAyLjQxOS01LjM3NSA1LjM3NXYyMS4yNWMwIDIuOTU2IDIuNDE5IDUuMzc1IDUuMzc1IDUuMzc1aDIxLjI1YzIuOTU2IDAgNS4zNzUtMi40MTkgNS4zNzUtNS4zNzV2LTIxLjI1YzAtMi45NTYtMi40MTktNS4zNzUtNS4zNzUtNS4zNzV6TTEyIDI2aC00di0xNGg0djE0ek0xMCAxMGMtMS4xMDUgMC0yLTAuODk1LTItMnMwLjg5NS0yIDItMiAyIDAuODk1IDIgMi0wLjg5NSAyLTIgMnpNMjYgMjZoLTR2LThjMC0xLjEwNS0wLjg5NS0yLTItMnMtMiAwLjg5NS0yIDJ2OGgtNHYtMTRoNHYyLjQ4M2MwLjgyNS0xLjEzMyAyLjA4Ni0yLjQ4MyAzLjUtMi40ODMgMi40ODUgMCA0LjUgMi4yMzkgNC41IDV2OXoiPjwvcGF0aD48L3N2Zz4=);
}

.share-pinterest{
    background-color: #ca212a;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr{
    background-color: #36465d;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mas botones</title>
    </head>
 <body>
  
  <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
  <div class="share-buttons-row">
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-fb"></div>
   <!--Twitter's Button -->
   <div class="share-twitter"></div>
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
   <!--Linkedin's Button -->
   <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
   <!--Pinterest's Button -->
   <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
   <!--Tumblr's Button -->
   <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
  </div>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </body>
```

Comment: No es que me queje .. pero a que se debe el cambio de respuesta aceptada?  La de Álvaro está muy bien

Comment: Lo siento,@ lois6b seria por error, ya he corregido. pues como bien dices esta muy bien su respuesta, y su molestia se tomo incluso perfeccionando la misma. Pido disculpas si hice algo malo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es otro ejemplo en el que realmente no necesitas nada de JavaScript, tan sólo con CSS puedes obtener lo que quieres. La pregunta sería más bien "¿cómo lo quieres?"

He dejado tu código HTML y JS exactamente igual, he cambiado un poco el código para `.share-buttons-row`y le he añadido un efecto cuando se le pasa el ratón por encima. En total, lo único que he cambiado/añadido en tu código son estas tres reglas:

```
.share-buttons-row {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.share-buttons-row::before {
  content: "+";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.share-buttons-row:hover {
  width: auto;
}
```

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando:

```js
$(function() {

  const ARTICLE_TITLE = document.title;
  const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

  $('.share-fb').click(function() {
    open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
  });

  $('.share-twitter').click(function() {
    open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
  });

  $('.share-google-plus').click(function() {
    open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
  });

  $('.share-linkedin').click(function() {
    open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&title=' + ARTICLE_TITLE + '&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
  });

  $('.share-pinterest').click(function() {
    open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&media=' + MAIN_IMAGE_URL + '&description=' + ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
  });

  $('.share-tumblr').click(function() {
    open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&name=' + ARTICLE_TITLE + '&description=' + ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
  });

  function open_window(url, name) {
    window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
  }
});
```

```css
.share-buttons-row {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.share-buttons-row::before {
  content: "+";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.share-buttons-row:hover {
  width: auto;
}

.share-buttons-row>div:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.share-buttons-row>div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .3em;
  padding: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.share-fb {
  background-color: #2d609b;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter {
  background-color: #00c3f3;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus {
  background-color: #eb4026;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin {
  background-color: #0074a1;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48IURPQ1RZUEUgc3ZnIFBVQkxJQyAiLS8vVzNDLy9EVEQgU1ZHIDEuMS8vRU4iICJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9HcmFwaGljcy9TVkcvMS4xL0RURC9zdmcxMS5kdGQiPjxzdmcgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiIgZD0iTTI2LjYyNSAwaC0yMS4yNWMtMi45NTYgMC01LjM3NSAyLjQxOS01LjM3NSA1LjM3NXYyMS4yNWMwIDIuOTU2IDIuNDE5IDUuMzc1IDUuMzc1IDUuMzc1aDIxLjI1YzIuOTU2IDAgNS4zNzUtMi40MTkgNS4zNzUtNS4zNzV2LTIxLjI1YzAtMi45NTYtMi40MTktNS4zNzUtNS4zNzUtNS4zNzV6TTEyIDI2aC00di0xNGg0djE0ek0xMCAxMGMtMS4xMDUgMC0yLTAuODk1LTItMnMwLjg5NS0yIDItMiAyIDAuODk1IDIgMi0wLjg5NSAyLTIgMnpNMjYgMjZoLTR2LThjMC0xLjEwNS0wLjg5NS0yLTItMnMtMiAwLjg5NS0yIDJ2OGgtNHYtMTRoNHYyLjQ4M2MwLjgyNS0xLjEzMyAyLjA4Ni0yLjQ4MyAzLjUtMi40ODMgMi40ODUgMCA0LjUgMi4yMzkgNC41IDV2OXoiPjwvcGF0aD48L3N2Zz4=);
}

.share-pinterest {
  background-color: #ca212a;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr {
  background-color: #36465d;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Mas botones</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
  <div class="share-buttons-row">
    <!--Facebook's Button -->
    <div class="share-fb"></div>
    <!--Twitter's Button -->
    <div class="share-twitter"></div>
    <!--Facebook's Button -->
    <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
    <!--Linkedin's Button -->
    <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
    <!--Pinterest's Button -->
    <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
    <!--Tumblr's Button -->
    <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

---

A partir de ahí, podrías animarlo un poco añadiendo animaciones/transiciones CSS, como por ejemplo, haciendo que el ancho crezca progresivamente mostrando los botones uno a uno (lo que se consigue tan sólo añadiendo 2 líneas más al CSS):

```js
$(function() {

  const ARTICLE_TITLE = document.title;
  const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

  $('.share-fb').click(function() {
    open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
  });

  $('.share-twitter').click(function() {
    open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
  });

  $('.share-google-plus').click(function() {
    open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
  });

  $('.share-linkedin').click(function() {
    open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&title=' + ARTICLE_TITLE + '&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
  });

  $('.share-pinterest').click(function() {
    open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&media=' + MAIN_IMAGE_URL + '&description=' + ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
  });

  $('.share-tumblr').click(function() {
    open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=' + ARTICLE_URL + '&name=' + ARTICLE_TITLE + '&description=' + ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
  });

  function open_window(url, name) {
    window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
  }
});
```

```css
.share-buttons-row {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.share-buttons-row:hover {
  width: auto;
  width: calc(280px + 2.1em);
}

.share-buttons-row::before {
  content: "+";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}



.share-buttons-row>div:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.share-buttons-row>div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .3em;
  padding: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.share-fb {
  background-color: #2d609b;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter {
  background-color: #00c3f3;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus {
  background-color: #eb4026;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin {
  background-color: #0074a1;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-pinterest {
  background-color: #ca212a;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr {
  background-color: #36465d;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Mas botones</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
  <div class="share-buttons-row">
    <!--Facebook's Button -->
    <div class="share-fb"></div>
    <!--Twitter's Button -->
    <div class="share-twitter"></div>
    <!--Facebook's Button -->
    <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
    <!--Linkedin's Button -->
    <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
    <!--Pinterest's Button -->
    <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
    <!--Tumblr's Button -->
    <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: muy chula la respuesta... el css no es lo mio HAHAH no se si solo me pasa a mi pero en el snippet de la animacion, el ultimo elemento tarda  mas que el resto en aparecer (https://imgur.com/a/7SFqP)

Comment: Sí, tarda más porque no le había puesto una función de tiempo y por defecto tiene una que es más rápida al principio que al final. La he cambiado a `linear` y ahora ya salen todos a la misma velocidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlvaroMontoro y como no a lois6b, me quedo con la respuesta de Alvaro, las dos no puedo. Gracias

Comment: ¿Como descubro mas botones que tenga esta librería @AlvaroMontoro ? Quiero añadir algunas redes mas: whasstsApp, Instagran, etc. Mi idea es mostrar los botones de, por ejemplo facebook y twitter y el signo de mas donde aparezcan el resto. ¿ Eso seria posible? No encontré mas que estos botones en el ejemplo. Gracias

Comment: @MariCruzFernandez La verdad es que para WhatsApp o Instagram, no sé cómo sería siempre me he limitado a Facebook, Twitter, Google+ y LinkedIn. Sobre lo de mostrar FB y Twitter y el +, [aquí puedes ver un ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/fmavzrd4/), pero he tenido que cambiar un poco el código.

Comment: Gracias por tu  ayuda @Alvaro Montoro seguiré buscando lo de los otros botones.

Comment: Y si quiero seguir insertando, que función debo utilizar o solo pegar el botón dentro del div ?

Comment: @EstebanVillaRodriguez tendrías que pegar el nuevo botón dentro del `div` y además en el CSS ajustar el ancho del `div` cuando se haga `:hover`.

Answer (score 10):

Puedes usar las funciones `mouseenter` y `mouseleave` para detectar cuando el raton está encima del boton o no.

Y luego la funcion `show` o `hide` para mostrar u ocultar, pasando un parametro opcional de milisegundos que tiene que tardar en hacer la animacion para que quede más vistoso.

```js
var flag =  false;

$("#botones").mouseenter(function() {
  if(!flag){
    flag =true;
    $("#resto").show(200, function(){
      flag = false;
    });
  }
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $("#resto").hide(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="botones">
  <button id="principal">Redes Sociales</button>
  <div id="resto" hidden>
    <button>Facebook</button>
    <button>Twitter</button>
    <button>LinkedIn</button>
    <button>Gooogle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```